# Android - Error in XML files

Tags: java, android, xml

So I am building a project but my R.Java got deleted somehow (reasons?) and it shows R can't b resolved into a variable,what to do now? Also no main.out.xml is there in my layout so no problems there.

Another problem is with my XML file in the two lines at bottom it shows these errors respectively:

1 - Error parsing XML no element found(No idea what this means.)

2 - XML document structure must start end end within the same entity.(Can't find an unclosed tag,help me!)

Here's my troubled XML file's code:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/imgthing"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" >
    </EditText>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:background="@drawable/imgthing"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="TextView" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/imgthing"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="RadioButton" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="RadioButton" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="RadioButton" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="RadioButton" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="RadioButton" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="RadioButton" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Also, when I view this in Graphical layout, then no radio buttons are visible in it. And if it matters, I have a white background in it.
EDIT:The second error is gone, reposted the code, it has only the first error.

Comment: Clean and build your project... Use ctrl+a and ctrl+shift+f to format your code .. You might find some minor syntax errors ..

Comment: What do you mean by build project? you mean retyping the code again or something else? Sorry, if this is a stupid question because I'm new to android development.

Comment: No.. no... First format your code like I said.. Then select your project and in eclipse do  --> Project--> Clean.

Comment: Hey, I would recommend reading about the basics again, and not writing any further code. It will be a bit boring, but it will stand to you. It's too easy to patch something up without getting the concepts. Building, cleaning etc your project are things you need to know about. As I said it's a bit boring, but well worth it. You could have ended up retyping all your code again for starters! I hope it doens't sound like I'm being harsh, I learned all this stuff VERY BADLY due to getting quick fixes and solutions online and it has cost me MONTHS of work now that it has caught up with me!

Comment: @TheLostMind Did the same,second error gone but first is still there and how to bring R.java back?

Comment: @AmanB. - Add another </LinearLayout> at the end of your code.. thanks to Erick :P

Comment: @RossC I am learning the basics,through video tutorials of mybringback.com (is it good?).Yeah,you're right but the documentation is bit boring and the words used to explain things there are too complicated,for me. I don't know what to do?

Comment: @TheLostMind Did it but the error is still there:no element found!

Comment: Ah you can't learn it all at once. The mistakes, errors, things you just blanked on will all teach you. I totally agree the wording is often terrible, and many are written in complete jargon at the best of times. It does get easier. Just keep going at it and don't think you'll understand all of it. Nobdoy knows it all, you just add little bits of knowledge as you go. Then read back over docs again later and you will understand a little more! If it is too complicated, break it down into smaller bits. It's all just layers on top of each other really. Keep at it! :)

Comment: format the code and repost it here...

Comment: @TheLostMind Never mind!! As you suggested I saved it and cleaned it again,it worked! thanks a ton!

Comment: @RossC Thanks for the tip! I will start reading it again as I had left reading it long before because I was feeling like i wasn't moving forward. But I think if you are saying it then it will be worth it because you look like an experienced one here.Thank you.

Comment: @AmanB. Nooooope! I'm not 'experienced' or any good at all. I'm actually using S.O. to UNDO the damage I've done by not learning things properly. I STILL get muddled with Static methods and other basic concepts. So now when I'm writing a little code I read some of the docs, even for the basics, as it kind of makes you learn how to read the documents. For an easy example System.out.println. Out is in itallics in Eclipse... Why? What does it do? So I read this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html  and then have a look at "public static final PrintStream out" and so on!

Comment: @RossC Alright,I will do the same and get back to you on that. But can I continue making projects at the same time?

Comment: @AmanB. absolutely! I'd just spend a little more time reading and researching! The goal is to learn, not to have an application up and running first time. All the mistakes, confusion, big nonsense words etc will teach you over time. It is a skill you learn from doing, just be wary of copy and paste others code at this stage! :) You've got the right attitude and that's 90% of it! As my mate who works in a research lab coding kernels in C says "google, stack overflow and just your attitude" is most of the job! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to close your parent layout, just close it and you will be ok!

Add at the end of the file

```
 </LinearLayout>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! Putting </LinearLayout> and saving+cleaning ,fixed all the errors. But still,I can't see my radio buttons in Graphical Layout. Some help please!

Comment: @AmanB. Is your third linear layout orientation correct? It's set to horizontal. And you are using weight sum, you set the weight only for *RadioGroups*. What about the other childs?

Comment: Yeah it worked all my radio buttons are in a vertical line now,anyways forget it..I am off this project. I guess I will read the documentation again. Thank you!

Comment: @AmanB. Do not give up, I'm sure you'll master it in no time!

Comment: How to learn this? because each time I read documentation I get more confused,so complicated words!! How did you do it?

Comment: @AmanB. It's hard to understand sometimes. I always followed http://developer.android.com/. If you open the sdk folder, you'll find some samples. Always ask like you did today, join some Android Developers groups like this one: https://plus.google.com/u/1/communities/105153134372062985968. As I said, you will master it in no time!

Comment: Thanks for the motivation,Eric! I will do the same. :)